# Integral of product of exponential and modified Bessel function

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions, integral-inequality

I need to evaluate or upper bound the below integral for arbitrary real positive values of $(a,b,r)$:
$$\int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi}\frac{\exp\left(-a\cos(\phi)\right)\cdot\mathrm{I}_1\left(2r\sqrt{b+a\cos(\phi)}\right) }{\sqrt{b+a\cos(\phi)}}\mathrm{d}\phi$$
Thanks.

Comment: The following might help: $I_1 (x) = \frac{x}{\pi }\int_{ - 1}^1 {e^{ - xt} \sqrt {1 - t^2 } dt}  = \frac{{xe^x }}{\pi }\int_0^2 {e^{ - xs} s^{1/2} \sqrt {2 - s} ds} 
\\ \le \sqrt 2 \frac{{xe^x }}{\pi }\int_0^2 {e^{ - xs} s^{1/2} ds}  \le \sqrt 2 \frac{{xe^x }}{\pi }\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} s^{1/2} ds}  = \sqrt 2 \frac{{e^x }}{{\pi \sqrt x }}\Gamma \left( {\frac{3}{2}} \right)
\\ = \frac{{e^x }}{{\sqrt {2\pi x} }}.
$
Note that $I_1 (x) \sim \frac{{e^x }}{{\sqrt {2\pi x} }}$ as $x\to +\infty$, so this upper bound is realistic.

Comment: That's right. Using this I can bound it as $$\frac{\exp(b+r^2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{\phi=0}^{2\pi} \frac{\exp(-(r-\sqrt{b+a\cos(\phi)})^2)}{(b+a\cos(\phi))} \mathrm{d}\phi$$

Comment: There should be a power of $3/4$ in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the denominator is $(b+a\cos(\phi))^{3/4}$. But still I need to simplify it more.

Comment: It depends on what you want. Clearly, the integral is at most $2\pi/(b-a)$.

Comment: I need an upper bound in terms of $(r,b,a)$ if possible.

Comment: Does anybody know why I got negative points for this question?! 
I believe this is a well-defined problem and the desired answer for me should be at least scalable with $r$, e.g, like $\exp(r)/r$. I don't see any reason for negative points!

Comment: Thanks for for the positive point, so that it became $0$ now.